# Animation with UIBezierPath - Object gets fixed on the top left corner

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to create an animation in swift to make a few ballons float from the bottom of the screen to the top. However in the middle of the animation one of the balloons gets fixed on the top left corner of the screen and does not disappear even when the animation finishes.

Please watch this video to see what I am talking about:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPHBn.jpg

Here is my code. I don't really know what I am doing wrong.

```
func presentVictoryView() {

        blackView.isHidden = false

        for _ in 0 ... 20 {

            let objectView = UIView()
            objectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            objectView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 100)
            //objectView.backgroundColor = .clear
            //objectView.alpha = CGFloat(0.9)
            objectView.isHidden = false


            let ballon = UILabel()
            ballon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            ballon.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 100)
            //ballon.backgroundColor = .clear
            //ballon.alpha = CGFloat(0.9)
            ballon.text = ""
            ballon.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60)
            objectView.addSubview(ballon)


            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                ballon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objectView.centerXAnchor),
                ballon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objectView.centerYAnchor)
            ])

            blackView.addSubview(objectView)

            let randomXOffset = Int.random(in: -120 ..< 200)

            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 270 + randomXOffset, y: 1000))
            path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100 + randomXOffset, y: -300), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 300 - randomXOffset, y: 600), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 70 + randomXOffset, y: 300))

            let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            animation.path = path.cgPath
            animation.repeatCount = 1

            animation.duration = Double.random(in: 4.0 ..< 7.0)
            //animation.timeOffset = Double(arc4random_uniform(50))

            objectView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animate position along path")

        }

        //objectView.isHidden = true


        //self?.newGame()
    }
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use delegate to detect end of animation and remove bubbleView then.

```
func presentVictoryView() {

    blackView.isHidden = false

    for _ in 0 ... 20 {

        let objectView = UIView()
        objectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        objectView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 100)
        //objectView.backgroundColor = .clear
        //objectView.alpha = CGFloat(0.9)
        objectView.isHidden = false

        let ballon = UILabel()
        ballon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ballon.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 20, height: 100)
        //ballon.backgroundColor = .clear
        //ballon.alpha = CGFloat(0.9)
        ballon.text = ""
        ballon.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60)
        objectView.addSubview(ballon)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ballon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objectView.centerXAnchor),
            ballon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: objectView.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        blackView.addSubview(objectView)

        let randomXOffset = Int.random(in: -120 ..< 200)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 270 + randomXOffset, y: 1000))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100 + randomXOffset, y: -300), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 300 - randomXOffset, y: 600), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 70 + randomXOffset, y: 300))

        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        animation.path = path.cgPath
        animation.repeatCount = 1

        // add these
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        let delegate = BubbleAnimDelegate()
        delegate.didFinishAnimation = {
            objectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        animation.delegate = delegate
        // upto here

        animation.duration = Double.random(in: 4.0 ..< 7.0)
        //animation.timeOffset = Double(arc4random_uniform(50))

        objectView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "animate position along path")

    }
    //objectView.isHidden = true
    //self?.newGame()
}

class BubbleAnimDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {

    var didFinishAnimation: (()->Void)?

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        didFinishAnimation?()
    }
}
```